# How to rotate camera in computer graphics using 4x4 matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, 3d, rotational-matrices

I have an initial rotation matrix of

```cpp
glm::mat3 rotationMatrix(
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0
);
```

and an initial camera position of `glm::vec3 cameraPosition({0.0, 0.0, 2.0});`

And hence when I want to transpose a point (`worldVertex`) from the world coordinate system to the camera coordinate system, I can make a matrix as follows:

```cpp
glm::mat4 cameraToWorld = glm::mat4(
    rotationMatrix[0][0], rotationMatrix[0][1], rotationMatrix[0][2], cameraPosition.x,
    rotationMatrix[1][0], rotationMatrix[1][1], rotationMatrix[1][2], cameraPosition.y,
    rotationMatrix[2][0], rotationMatrix[2][1], rotationMatrix[2][2], cameraPosition.z,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
);
glm::mat4 worldToCamera = glm::inverse(cameraToWorld);
glm::vec4 newWorldVertex(worldVertex.x, worldVertex.y, worldVertex.z, 1.0);
glm::vec4 cameraPoint = newWorldVertex * worldToCamera;
// hence we can get our new x, y, z from cameraPoint
```

The problem comes when I try and rotate the camera view with respect to the world origin. For example, if I want to rotate 90deg anti-clockwise about the x-axis, I thought I could do something like:

```cpp
additionalRotationMatrix = glm::mat3(
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, cos(90), sin(90),
    0.0, -sin(90), cos(90)
);
```

However, at this point I am confused on what to do. I tried multiplying it by my existing `rotationMatrix` and updating the `rotationMatrix` to be the result. I also tried multiplying it by the `cameraPosition` vector (`vec4` with a `1` as `w`).

Also, after transposing the point I am getting the 2D plane intersection point in order to draw it.

I can do translations fine by just adding or subtracting from the correct dimension of the `cameraPosition` vector.

I should note that I'm always passing `rotationMatrix` and `cameraPosition` by value.

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: There are whole courses on that, it is not something answered quickly here.  You usually have to combine serveral matrix transformations to get the result you want. In this case you need to translate from your camera to world origin, rotate and do an inverse translation.

Comment: @appleapple I can't rotate the camera

Comment: @PepijnKramer can you give an example please?

Comment: @JP what does that mean? do you multiply camera position with the the matrix and it doesn't change? do you multiply object position and it doesn't change? or any other combinations?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes I have studied it. Hence the progression I have made in my post. But I'm stuck on putting together the last step. I don't think a project environment is necessary, a simple LaTeX example or anything would be very helpful

Comment: @appleapple It's not behaving as desired. I expect I am missing a component to actually be rotating with respect to the world origin. The coordinates I get end up way off the screen

Comment: Let me double check, I see you are trying to do the translate + rotate + translate back. Though it requires some serious going back in my memory for this one ;)

Comment: I think I see where it goes off (if I remember correctly, last did this in 1994 or so)...  You have a rotation matrix which you then invert, but you should invert a translation matrix. Step 1. Create a translation (not a rotation matrix). Step 2. Rotate (matrix multiply). Step 3. Apply inverse translatio matrix.

Comment: @JP it'd be easier to understand with [mcve]. with fixed camera position and object position. multiply with the matrix and output the result. matrix itself doesn't do transform, it need to apply to a vector to do so, but you don't show the relevant parts.